# Accessing host services from systemd-nspawn containers

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, containers

I've got a set of containers managed by [systemd-nspawn](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-nspawn.html). The containers should be (semi-)isolated from the external network, but at the same time should be able to access non-containerized services like DBMS, running on the host (see [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSYLv.png)). The networking is managed by `systemd-networkd` on both ends.

I've tried the following most common private network modes of systemd-nspawn:

#### Virtual Ethernet

`-n, --network-veth` creates a pair of connected virtual ethernet adapters per container, one on the host side, another inside the container. Seems like this is of little use, because it is not clear which address the DBMS should listen on and which address the containers should connect to.

#### Bridge

`--network-bridge=` does mostly the same, but adds virtual adapters to the specified bridge. The bridge should be already setup and assigned an IP:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/br0.netdev 
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

```
# /etc/systemd/network/br0.network 
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
Address=169.254.1.1/16
```

This config has proven to be working, but requires additional bridge configuration and is generally problematic when it comes to external network access for the containers.

#### Zone

`--network-zone=` does the same, but manages the bridge interface automatically. Here's what we get by default for the bridge:

```
[root@host ~]# ip addr show vz-containers
26: vz-containers: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 169.254.120.107/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link vz-containers
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global vz-containers
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.1.1/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global vz-containers
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Seems like it's assigned a random address from `169.254.0.0/16`, and two static addresses `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.1.1`. The host is reachable from the containers by these two addresses. But it's unclear where these addresses come from, and I'm not sure this won't change in the future versions of systemd. To make sure, we can assign an additional static IP to the bridge interface:

```
# /etc/systemd/network/80-container-vz.network - full override, systemd < 232 
[Match]
Name=vz-*
Driver=bridge

[Network]
# Default to using a /24 prefix, giving up to 253 addresses per virtual network.
Address=0.0.0.0/24
Address=169.254.1.1/24
# the rest is left as in the original /usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-vz.network
```

```
# /etc/systemd/network/80-container-vz.network.d/override.conf - drop-in, systemd ≥ 232
[Network]
Address=169.254.1.1/24
```

This works well, doesn't pose problems with external net connectivity, but also requires additional monkeying with the bridge configuration. Additionally, both methods (bridge and zone) require configuring static `/etc/hosts` entry, as `systemd-resolved` and friends (`mymachines`, `myhostname` and `resolve` NSS modules) are not very helpful here:

```
# /etc/hosts
169.254.1.1 host
```

Luckily, all the containers share the same base OS image, so it's not that hard to do.

The question is, can all of the above be done in a simpler manner? Or should I wait until `systemd-nspawn` gets some magic option like "make the host accessible in the containers by the <foo> hostname"?

Answer (score 1):

Was running into the same complications - my answers are more or less the same as Kiraly's but with the configuration controlled 100% by the host.

The stock `/lib/systemd/network/80-container-ve.network` can be copied and modified to set a host address on a specific static IP (you will also need to update the `[Match]`)

Then - set a DHCP pool with only 1 address. That way its predictable - and the container doesn't need to be statically configured, it just picks up the right address on boot.

So - something like this

`/etc/systemd/network/50-mycont.network`

```
[Match]
# Hard match for the container interface name - no wildcards
Name=ve-mycont
Driver=veth

[Network]
# Static address for host
Address=10.0.60.49/28
LinkLocalAddressing=yes
DHCPServer=yes
IPMasquerade=yes
LLDP=yes
EmitLLDP=customer-bridge

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=2
PoolSize=1
# Little DHCP - container will have address 10.0.60.50
```

Answer (score 0):

> it's unclear where these addresses come from

If you are using systemd-networkd, then configuration files come from configuration files with a .network extension. These files are located in
`/etc/systemd/network` or `/run/systemd/network` or `/usr/lib/systemd/network` - the later is the default if you did not modify anything in /etc. ... 
The documentation for systemd-networkd is [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#). You may have a DHCP server on your network, and depending which networking mode you use, IP addresses might get assigned from that DHCP server.

> The question is, can all of the above be done in a simpler manner?

Most databases are network-based, they listen on a specific port on the host. Depending on your networking configuration, your host should have an interface with an IP address, that is on the host side, but reachable from containers. Keep in mind that firewalling and masquerade might also play a significant role. Once connectivity is established, make sure your database server is listening on the given interface as well.

> make the host accessible in the containers by the  hostname

Since you are in control of your host-side IP address, you can put an entry into `/etc/hosts`, as you did. I'm not aware of any simpler solutions, or any external solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still (as of Feb 2024) no proper solution for this, I found a rather elegant way to make this work by just a minimal customization inside the container.

1. Add the following two lines to `/etc/hosts` (the addresses will be replaced later; the word “host” is the symbolic hostname assigned to the container host):

   ```
   0.0.0.0 host
   :: host
   ```
2. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/host-address.service` with the following contents inside the container:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Add IP address of host system to /etc/hosts
   After=network-online.target

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec sed -i -r "s#^[0-9.]+(\\\\s*host)\\$#$(ip -4 route show default | cut -d" " -f3 | head -n1)\\1#" /etc/hosts'
   ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec sed -i -r "s#^[0-9A-Fa-f:]+(\\\\s*host)\\$#$(ip -6 route show default | cut -d" " -f3 | head -n1)\\1#" /etc/hosts'
   RemainAfterExit=yes

   [Install]
   WantedBy=network-online.target
   ```
3. Enable and start the added service by running:
   `systemctl enable --now host-address.service`
4. `/etc/hosts` should now contain the container host’s IPv4 and IPv6 address and `ping host` et al should work

Note that this doesn’t require manually assigning any IP addresses at any point. It just adds the information already added by systemd-networkd to the container’s system state in a place that is much more accessible by most tools than just the routing configuration. Since the unit is ordered to run after `network-online.target`, it will be started after `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` has finished and hence after systemd-networkd has set up the networking information on the `host0` interface, making this configuration reboot-safe and hopefully pretty reliable.